# It was or was it is the right order

Tags: word-order

Does someones knows what is the right order? Where do I put 'it was'

A)"A shocking moment it was and I became dreadfully afraid to open my eyes.."

V)"It was a shocking moment and I became dreadfully afraid to open my eyes.."

Comment: Can be used in regular speech for confirmation of a statement made earlier without sounding like Yoda, like: "He warned me it would be a shocking moment. A shocking moment it was."

Answer (score -1):

Option V is standard, whereas Option A sounds odd or like there's an overwhelming need to emphasize the information appearing first.

Option V is more usual ("It was a shocking moment"), since it follows a standard expected order:

`subject ("it"), verb ("was"), and object or complement ("a shocking moment")`

SVO is the standard pattern for syntax in English. However, some reorganization of this pattern can be attempted for English, in a process known as **[inversion](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/word-order-and-focus/inversion)** or [fronting](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/about-words-clauses-and-sentences/fronting). In the case of A, we have:

`Object or complement ("A shocking moment"), subject ("it"), verb ("was")`

Not many languages use this pattern regularly. In English, the most famous regular speaker in this syntax is [Yoda](https://www.theatlantic.com/entertainment/archive/2015/12/hmmmmm/420798/). You only want to write with this syntax when the need to emphasize the object/complement is so urgent that it overwhelms ordinary syntax. (In other words, you [front](https://theweek.com/articles/442256/why-strangely-yoda-speaks) the information.)

Of course, you can use it all the time to sound like a Jedi Master.

Comment: This is complicated by the fact that dummy _it_ is also used.

Comment: I think perhaps this answer is a bit too heavy on the cautionary tales – yes, fronting is done for effect and shouldn’t be overused, but it’s not quite as rare or requires quite as much overwhelming emphasis as you imply here. It’s a perfectly common approach to emphasise something in a sentence. @EdwinAshworth This isn’t a dummy _it_, just a regular _it_.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet  CGEL p 1483 (S2:5d) argues that 'dummy' status depends on degree of referentiality plus replaceability of 'it' by 'this'. And though they argue for (quasi-)referentiality with a similar example, you've really got to dig deep here to find a true referent (what transpired [next] ); 'A shocking moment is what occurred' is of course artificial.